# Catch assert false using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

The code in the file to test is:

```
public void testFail() {
    assert false;
}
```

I need to catch this using reflection and increment a "failed" counter. This is my attempt:

```
      try {
          Object t = c.newInstance();
          m[i].invoke(t, new Object[0]); // m is the array that holds all Methods for c
          passed ++;
      } catch (AssertionError ae) {
          failed ++;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          errors ++;
      }
    }
```

The assertFalse just goes through as passed and does not raise any exceptions. How can I catch this?

Thanks.

Comment: have you double checked if -ea is used at launching the VM?

Comment: `AssertionError` is a subclass of `Error` and is therefore an unchecked exception. You shouldn't really trying to catch unchecked exceptions.

Comment: @TheCat Ah, I see. So there isn't a way to do so?

Comment: You can still `catch` unchecked exceptions, you just don't have to. Does this code actually run the test. IE put a print out in the test or something?

Comment: When I run the class I'm testing and invoke the testFail() method, it doesn't raise any exceptions/errors.